# Comparing two Identically structured Dataframes in Spark

Tags: scala, sqlite, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

```
val originalDF = Seq((1,"gaurav","jaipur",550,70000),(2,"sunil","noida",600,80000),(3,"rishi","ahmedabad",510,65000)).toDF("id","name","city","credit_score","credit_limit")

val changedDF= Seq((1,"gaurav","jaipur",550,70000),(2,"sunil","noida",650,90000),(4,"Joshua","cochin",612,85000)).toDF("id","name","city","creditscore","credit_limit")
```

So the above two dataframes has the same table structure and I want to find out the id's for which the values have changed in the other dataframe(changedDF). I tried with the except() function in spark but its giving me two rows. Id is the common column between these two dataframes.

```
changedDF.except(originalDF).show
+---+------+------+-----------+------------+
| id|  name|  city|creditscore|credit_limit|
+---+------+------+-----------+------------+
|  4|Joshua|cochin|        612|       85000|
|  2| sunil| noida|        650|       90000|
+---+------+------+-----------+------------+
```

Whereas I only want the common ids for which there has been any changes.Like this ->

```
+---+------+------+-----------+------------+
| id|  name|  city|creditscore|credit_limit|
+---+------+------+-----------+------------+
|  2| sunil| noida|        650|       90000|
+---+------+------+-----------+------------+
```

Is there any way to find out the only the common ids for which the data have changed.
Can anybody tell me any approach I can follow to achieve this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do the `inner` join of the dataframes, that will give you the result with common ids.

```
originalDF.alias("a").join(changedDF.alias("b"), col("a.id") === col("b.id"), "inner")
  .select("a.*")
  .except(changedDF)
  .show
```

Then, your expected result will be out:

```
+---+-----+-----+------------+------------+
| id| name| city|credit_score|credit_limit|
+---+-----+-----+------------+------------+
|  2|sunil|noida|         600|       80000|
+---+-----+-----+------------+------------+
```